# Javascript shopping cart - need assistance with javascript portion, why isnt my code working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a javascript shopping cart. When you click on an item, the contents of that item are appended on the DOM via javascript. Having some difficulty with my code, specifically the sections where I bolded with '** **'

For my 'dropDown-amount' class, I have a number as the value but i cant seem to access that value later on in the code (see dropDown-price).

Also I have a For statement on my if/else statement that tries to loop through each index in 'items' array and to essentially count how many times one specific item is inside the list (so I can update quantity of x item on DOM) but having trouble getting everything to work. I know what I have to do to solve this problem and I know all 3 of these issues are linked together, just don't know what is exactly causing this to fail.

```js
//dropdown menu hidden
const cartDropdown = document.querySelector('.cart-dropDown-items');

//every single + symbol
const addToCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.addToCart');

//price of item
const foodPrices = document.querySelectorAll('.selection-row-title');

//name of item
const foodNames = document.querySelectorAll('.selection-row-foodName');

//weight of item
const foodWeights = document.querySelectorAll('.selection-row-weight');

const items = [];
let total = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
  addToCartButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    const newItem = document.createElement('div');
    newItem.className = 'dropDown-item';
    let amountItems = document.querySelector('.amount-items');

    newItem.innerHTML =
      `<div class='dropDown-title dropDown-info'>
                ${foodNames[i].innerHTML}
            </div>
            <div class='dropDown-amount dropDown-info'>
                **<p class='amount-items'>${1}</p>**  
            </div>
            <div class='dropDown-price dropDown-info'> 
                **${Number(foodPrices[i].innerHTML.substring(1)) * Number(amountItems.textContent)}**
            </div>`;

    console.log(newItem)
    // if item currently exists in array, just update amount in checkout and increase count++
    if (items.includes(addToCartButtons[i].value)) {
      items.push(addToCartButtons[i].value); **
      for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].includes(addToCartButtons[i].value)) {
          Number(amountItems.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
      } **
    }
    // if items does not exist in array, update dom with new item UI and count = 1 by default
    else {
      items.push(addToCartButtons[i].value);
      cartDropdown.appendChild(newItem);


    }
    console.log(items)
  })
}
```

```css
.cart-dropDown-items {}

.dropDown-title {}

.dropDown-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.dropDown-info {}

.dropDown-title {
  width: 40%;
}

.dropDown-amount {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropDown-amount p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.dropDown-price {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!--cart dropDown-->
<div class='cart-dropDown'>
  <div class='cart-dropDown-header'>
    <p>My Carts</p>
    <p>Personal Cart</p>
    <p class='cart-dropDown-close'>Close</p>
  </div>
  <div class='cart-dropDown-items'>
    <!--
                        <div class='dropDown-item'>
                            <div class='dropDown-title dropDown-info'>Mixed bell pepper, 6 ct</div>
                            <div class='dropDown-amount dropDown-info'>1</div>
                            <div class='dropDown-price dropDown-info'>$9.84</div>
                        </div>
                        next unique item...
                        -->
  </div>
  <div class='cart-dropDown-checkout'>
    <div class='cart-dropDown-checkout1'>
      <p>Go to Checkout</p>
    </div>
    <div class='cart-dropDown-checkout2'>
      <p>$0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Markdown and HTML are turned off in code blocks. It won't bold.

Comment: which is the bootstrap version and jquery version

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej no bootstrap/jquery. Just plain html, css, and JS

Comment: you dont add full html and css because some item is missing in both

Comment: Can you add one complete section which we can run and test, just having code snippets which can't be run does not give the full picture. Maybe a codepen link will help others to debug the issue faster